# Handpose tfjs Error - No backend found in registry

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js, tfjs-node

When trying to run a demo project for Handpose tfjs, I get the below error.

[image]

My package.json file has below dependencies:

```
{
"name": "tensorflowJs",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development parcel index.html --no-hmr ",
  "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production parcel build index.html --public-url ./"
 },
"browser": {
"crypto": false
 },
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "@tensorflow-models/handpose": "0.0.4",
  "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm": "^2.0.0",
  "@tensorflow/tfjs-converter": "^1.7.4",
  "@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^2.0.0",
  "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^2.0.0",
  "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
  "cross-env": "^7.0.2"
 },
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.10.1",
  "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
  "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.10.1",
  "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
  "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4"
 }
}
```

The issue with the registry was supposed to be resolved after version 0.10.3, but even for version-2, I'm still facing the issue. Does anyone know why this issue occurs?

Comment: Did you set the backend to `wasm` as following `tf.setBackend('wasm')` ?

Comment: It seems likely to be an issue with tfjs. I'm getting the same error but am retrieving tfjs core from the web.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62177416/tfjs-core-reference-suddenly-stop-working-and-shows-no-backend-found-in-registr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-core"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/handpose"></script>
```

Tensorflow released 2.0.0, and now you must choose either tfjs-backend-webgl, tfjs-backend-cpu, or tfjs-backend-wasm to run your model. You're using handpose and for that you should use webgl.

Comment: Thanks.! That removed the error. And since the @tensorflow/tfjs has webGl backend default included, i didn't even had to include the script.

Answer (score 12):

I had mistakenly come up with my own import line:

```js
import backend from '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl'
```

### Correct version:

```js
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl';
```

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same error which **"No backend found in registry"** but in my case i was working with `@tensorflow-models/blazeface` model and a react app.I installed `@tensorflow/tfjs-converter` **and** `@tensorflow/tfjs-core` as the Readme [link to the Github Readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/blazeface) was suggesting but i was still getting the error. Then i solved my problem by going to the index.html in the public folder of a react app and i added the following scripts at the bottom of the file.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-core"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl"></script>
```

**Good luck**

Comment: I had the exact same problem but I just installed '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl'  without touching index.html and the error disappeared

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked after I added these two packages to the project:

```js
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl';
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to wait for tf to be ready:

```js
tf.ready().then(()=> {
  //Code here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the solutions here, and solutions in the net: for days. Then it occurred to me: *most of those problems on those cases are version issues*.

Then, I just copied a version working an app found in the net, and it works fine. Final learning: it seems an issue with versioning.

```
"@tensorflow-models/mobilenet": "1.0.1",//this one you should fix, the issue is here
"@tensorflow/tfjs": "2.0.0",//tested, you can install the latest version
```

Not sure we have a better solution, but it works just fine!
[image]