Installing @tensorflow/tfjs-node but receiving error "No backend found in registry"
I try to install @tensorflow/tfjs-node but receive this error
I have installed python and path to it.
I have installed:
"@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.18.0",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl": "^4.18.0",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-converter": "^4.18.0",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-core": "^4.18.0",

I run but Error:

No backend found in registry

So I tried to install @tensorflow/tfjs-node

Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134812/handpose-tfjs-error-no-backend-found-in-registry
